# Работа с PlayerPrefs

Tags: unity3d, unity3d-android

Сохраняю некоторые значения в своей игре через PlayerPrefs. В эмуляторе юнити всё сохраняется нормально, но при установке на телефон сохранения не происходят. В чём может быть проблема?

Comment: а вы в какой момент сохраняете? Попробуйте по нажатию кнопки сохранять, просто для тестирования) может просто не в тот момент

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У меня такой вариант. При нажатии кнопки "back" (на андроид), сохраняет нужную переменную.

```
if (Input.GetKeyUp(KeyCode.Escape))//Esc или кнопка назад на телефоне
    {
        PlayerPrefs.SetInt("Lifes", Lifes);
        PlayerPrefs.Save();
    }
```

Или при изменении переменной сразу сохранить.